# Binary Tree size function python

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I'm a beginner of Python and data structure, I have a problem with designing the binary tree size method, my code and my error are as follows

```
class BinaryTree:
    def get_left(self):
         return self.left
    def get_right(self):
         return self.right
    def set_data(self, data):
         self.data = data
    def get_data(self):
         return self.data

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def insert_left(self, new_data):
        if self.left == None:
            self.left = BinaryTree(new_data)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(new_data)
            t.left = self.left
            self.left = t
    def insert_right(self, new_data):
        if self.right == None:
            self.right = BinaryTree(new_data)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(new_data)
            t.right = self.right
            self.right = t
    def tree_size(self):
       if self== None:
           return 0
       else：
           if self.left != None and self.right!= None:
               return 1+ self.left.tree_size()+ self.right.tree_size()
           elif self.left!=None:
               return 1+ self.left.tree_size()
           elif self.right!=None:
               return 1+ self.right.tree_size()
           else:
               return 1
```

Getting below error,

> AttributeError: 'BinaryTree' object has no attribute 'tree_size'

Any help?

Comment: Probably no proper indentation? Please show the complete class.

Comment: @clemens add the complete class now, probably due to copy the format changed though, I've adjusted a little bit as well

Comment: I pasted your code into a file and got: _SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xef' in file bt.py on line 32, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details_. There are some invisible characters after `else:`. When I remove them it works for me.

Comment: Try passing self to tree size

Comment: Same here. The code works when you remove those mysterious characters at the end of the `else` block in `tree_size`.